# The IList model inside a model is not fetching in Get action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three models like below

1st

```
public partial class provider_preapproval
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

    .......
    public DateTime? sync_time { get; set; }

    public  IList<provider_diagnosis_dtls> provider_diagnosis_dtls { get; set; }

    public IList<provider_service_dtls> provider_service_dtls { get; set; }

}
```

2nd

```
 public partial class provider_diagnosis_dtls
 {
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public long diagnosis_id { get; set; }

     public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

     ..........................

 }
```

3rd

```
public partial class provider_service_dtls
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long service_id { get; set; }

    public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

    ..................
}
```

where `preapproval_id` in the first model is using as foreign key for the two while saving to db. It is successfully saving the details.

But when I call the model for displaying the `provider_diagnosis_dtls` and `provider_service_dtls` are coming as null as below :(

[image]

My controller

```
public ActionResult preapprove_detail(int preapprove_id)
{
    provider_preapproval requestHeader = new provider_preapproval();
    requestHeader = db.provider_preapproval.Find(preapprove_id);
    if (requestHeader != null)
    {
        return View(requestHeader);
    }
}
```

what's the wrong thing im doing. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists are null because there's no relationship specified between the types representing database records. In order to do it you'll need to specify navigation properties and decorate them with right combination of `ForeignKeyAttribute` and `InversePropertyAttribute`:

```
public partial class provider_preapproval
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("preapproval")]
    public virtual IList<provider_diagnosis_dtls> provider_diagnosis_dtls { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("preapproval")]
    public virtual IList<provider_service_dtls> provider_service_dtls { get; set; }

    //...
}

public partial class provider_diagnosis_dtls
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long diagnosis_id { get; set; }

    public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("preapproval_id"), InverseProperty("provider_diagnosis_dtls ")]
    public virtual provider_preapproval preapproval { get; set; }

    //...
}

public partial class provider_service_dtls
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long service_id { get; set; }

    public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("preapproval_id"), InverseProperty("provider_service_dtls")]
    public virtual provider_preapproval preapproval { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

Note that I marked navigation properties as `virtual` so that they are lazy-loaded (loaded from database upon accessing the property and not upon loading the "owner" object - it's somewhat an "on demand" loading policy).